# Dart литералы это ссылки?

Tags: dart, литерал

Литералы в Dart это объекты т.к. мы можем сделать так: print(5.runtimeType);
Получается что 5-это ссылка на ячейку памяти а не константа, хранящаяся прямо в коде?

Comment: Что мешает компилятору превратить целиком выражение `5.runtimeType` в константу хранящуюся прямо в коде? ([constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding))

Comment: Почему тогда компилятор не видит ошибку при изменении полей константного листа? Исключение в рантайме. Если он уже записан как const в коде? const list =[1,2,3]; list.add(4);

Comment: Потому что `constant folding` - оптимизация. Не известно в каких ситуациях она применяется. Я лишь привёл пример, чтобы обратить ваше внимание, что ваш вопрос опирается на конкретное представление о работе компилятора, а компилятор может работать по другому.